# Chakra UI Range Slider Filter Issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I don't understand why my RangeSlider is acting the way it does.

my price variable is a number.

I have a filters component which has the following RangeSlider from Chakra.

```
 <div className="pt-2 pl-2 pr-2 pb-2 gap-3">
      <RangeSlider
        defaultValue={getMinMax(item)}
        min={0}
        max={500000}
        step={10}
        colorScheme="teal"
        onChangeEnd={(price) => {
          setFilter({
            ...filter,
            price: price,
          });
          console.log("OnChangeEnd " + price);
          console.log("default value " + getMinMax(item));
        }}
      >
        <RangeSliderTrack
          height={4}
          bg="blue.500"
          color="white"
          borderRadius="md"
        >
          <RangeSliderFilledTrack />
        </RangeSliderTrack>
        <RangeSliderThumb index={0} />
        <RangeSliderThumb index={1} />
      </RangeSlider>
    </div>
```

The getMinMax function is as follows:

```
const getMinMax = (item) => {
const prices = item.map((item) => item.price);
const min = Math.min(...prices);
const max = Math.max(...prices);
return [min, max];
```

};

I then pass this through to another component called DataTable
which has a const called dataFiltered where I am already filtering some string variables but it isn't working for my price variable.

```
const dataFiltered = item?.filter((val) => {
const searchInput1 = `${val.description.toLowerCase()} || ${val.location.toLowerCase()} || ${val.suburb.toLowerCase()} || ${val.price.toString()}`;
// const searchInput2 =
return (
  searchInput1.includes(filter.search.toLowerCase()) &&
  (filter?.location?.length
    ? filter.location
        .map((v) => v.toLowerCase())
        .includes(val?.location?.toLowerCase()) ||
      filter.location.length === 0 // if no location is selected, show all
    : true) &&
  (filter?.description?.length
    ? filter.description
        .map((v) => v.toLowerCase())
        .includes(val?.description?.toLowerCase()) ||
      filter.description.length === 0 // if no description is selected, show all
    : true) &&
  (filter?.suburb?.length
    ? filter.suburb
        .map((v) => v.toLowerCase())
        .includes(val?.suburb?.toLowerCase()) || filter.suburb.length === 0 // if no suburb is selected, show all
    : true) &&
  (filter?.price?.length
    ? filter.price
        .map((v) => v.toString())
        .includes(val?.price?.toString()) || filter.price.length === 0 // if no price is selected, show all
    : true)
);
```

});